# add variable seconds to time foreach loop

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I'm building a queue to generate something and I want it visible for users to see how long it will take till the generation is ready.

So I have an estimated time it takes to generate something, but that is a variable because it can be anywhere between 5-120 seconds. And now I need to add the variable time to the time of the day and make a loop because the queue has more values.

So for example I need this:

Object 1 - Estimated generation time: 15 sec - 09:00:15

Object 2 - Estimated generation time: 20 sec - 09:00:35

Object 3 - Estimated generation time: 10 sec - 09:00:45

And so on..

I already tried this:

```
$my_time = date('h:i:s',time());
$seconds2add = $estimated_time;

$new_time= strtotime($my_time);
$new_time+=$seconds2add;

echo date('h:i:s',$new_time);
```

And:

```
$time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time() + $estimated_time);
```

It loops but both gives me like this output:

Object 1 - Estimated generation time: 15 sec - 09:00:15

Object 2 - Estimated generation time: 20 sec - 09:00:20

Object 3 - Estimated generation time: 10 sec - 09:00:10

So how can I make it loop that it works?

**Edit: This is my loop**

```
$this_time = date('h:i:s',time());
$my_time = $this_time;
$num = 1;
foreach($orders as $order) {
    echo '<tr>'
    . '<td>'.($num++).'</td>'
    . '<td>'. $order->url .'</td>'
    . '<td>'. $order->product_desc .'</td>'
    . '<td>'. $order->size .' cm</td>'
    . '<td>'. $order->estimated_time .' sec</td>';

$seconds2add = $order->estimated_time;
$my_time= strtotime($my_time);
$my_time+=$seconds2add;
    echo '<td>'. date('h:i:s',$my_time) . '</td>'
    . '</tr>';        
}
```

Comment: Your first line is wrong... You're doing all estimates by adding them to "Now" - not to when the previous item finished - eg now +15, _now_ +20 etc. What you want is Now + 15, Previous finish +20, Previous finish +10

Comment: @Basic that is indeed exactly what I want. But I can't figure out how to do it. What is wrong with my frist line?

Comment: When I outcomment the new_time= strtotime($my_time); it works, but makes the time 01:00 and not the current time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing your loop code might help, but here is the general idea of what you should do:

```
$current_time = time(); // seconds since unix epoch
echo 'Start: ' . date('h:i:s') . PHP_EOL;

while($you_do_stuff == true) {
    // do stuff
    $now = time();
    $time_taken = $now - $current_time;
    echo $time_taken . ' seconds to process: ' . date('h:i:s', $now) . PHP_EOL;

    // set current time to now
    $current_time = $now;
}

echo 'Finished: ' . date('h:i:s');
```

**Edit:** here's an example with a bunch of random "estimated times" in seconds:

```
// ... in seconds
$estimated_times = array(
  5,
  20,
  35,
  110
);

$current_time = time(); // seconds since unix epoch
echo 'Start: ' . date('h:i:s') . PHP_EOL;

foreach($estimated_times as $estimated_time) {
    // add estimated time to current time (this increases each loop)
    $current_time += $estimated_time;
    // output estimated time and finish time
    echo 'Estimated time: ' . $estimated_time . ' seconds: ' . date('h:i:s', $current_time) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/117021)

Comment: Where is the estimated time added?

Comment: It's a generic example, if you post your loop code I'll show you how to work it in.

Comment: I added you code to my loop and edited a bit. Its working like a charm now. Thank you :)